# Linked list search function not working properly

Tags: c++, class, search, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am making a LinkedList class in C++ with its methods, like adding nodes, traversing, and searching. When implementing the search function, it seems not working properly because it does not find the value in linked list when in fact it is inside the linked list. The code is shown below.

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
    public:
        int value;
        Node* next;
        
        Node(int value, Node* next) {
            this->value = value;
            this->next = next;
        }
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    
    LinkedList() {
        this->head = nullptr;
        this->tail = nullptr;
    }
    
    LinkedList(Node* node) {
        this->head = node;
        this->tail = node;
    }
    
    void addNodeFront(Node* node) {
        if(head==nullptr && tail==nullptr) {
            this->head = node;
            this->tail = node;
            return;
        }
        this->tail = this->head;
        this->head = node;
        node->next = tail;
    }
    
    void addNodeBack(Node* node) {
        if(head==nullptr && tail==nullptr) {
            this->head = node;
            this->tail = node;
            return;
        }
        this->tail->next = node;
        this->tail = node;
    }
    
    void addNodeAfterNode(Node* prevNode, Node* node) {
        node->next = prevNode->next;
        prevNode->next = node;
    }
    
    bool searchVal(int val) {
        while(this->head != nullptr) {
            if(this->head->value == val) return true;
            this->head = this->head->next;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    void deleteNode(Node* node) {
        Node* prevNode = this->head;
        while(prevNode->next != node) {
            
        }
    }
    
    void traverseLinkedList() {
        while(this->head!=nullptr) {
            std::cout << this->head->value << "->";
            this->head = this->head->next;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    void sortLinkedList() {
        
    }
};

int main() {
    Node node1(2,nullptr);
    Node node2(4,nullptr);
    Node node3(3,nullptr);
    LinkedList ls;
    ls.addNodeFront(&node1);
    ls.addNodeBack(&node3);
    ls.addNodeAfterNode(&node3, &node2);
    ls.traverseLinkedList();
    if(ls.searchVal(4)) std::cout << "value found\n";
    else std::cout << "value not found\n";
}
```

When I call the `searchVal()` function inside the `main` function it outputs `value not found` while value 4 is inside the linked list. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Why is `searchVal()` changing the value of `this->head`?  Use a local variable to iterate instead (e.g. `Node * n = this->head; while(n != nullptr) {...}`, that way calling `searchVal()` won't destroy your linked list as a side effect.  (Changing the signature of the method to `bool searchVal(int val) const` will allow the compiler to help you implement the method correctly, since then the compiler won't allow you to change the state of your linked list inside the method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I call the searchVal() function inside the main function it
> outputs value not found while value 4 is inside the linked list. What
> is wrong with my code?

Just before you call `searchVal(4)` you call `traverseLinkedList()`, and `traverseLinkedList()` is implemented in such a way that when it returns, `this->head` will be `NULL`, which means that at that point your linked list is empty (and you have leaked memory).  You'll want to modify `traverseLinkedList()` and `searchVal()` to not change the value of `this->head` (or any other member-variables of the `LinkedList` object) so that they don't modify the state of the list as a side effect.

Comment: I see, I've edited the code and it works now. Thank you.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `const` modifier for the class method here?

Comment: It's not strictly necessary, but it's very helpful to tag any method that you know is not supposed to modify the state of the object as `const`, because then the compiler will emit an error if it detects any code inside the method that is trying to modify the state of the object.  Catching more errors at compile-time saves you time and effort because it cuts down on the amount of debugging you'll have to do to get your program running correctly.